# Late binding for Word objects in an Excel VBA application are not working

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA application written in Excel that opens Word documents and manipulates them.

I believe I want to use Late Binding because:

1. I don't want the user to have to add the reference library
2. I don't know what version of Excel / Word they are on anyway.

So to use late binding, I understand you must first declare the object "as Object":

```
Dim oWordApp As Object
Dim oActiveDoc As Object
Dim oSection As Object
Dim oSections As Object
Dim oTable As Object
Dim oTables As Object
```

Then, in the procedure, create the objects with the appropriate library reference:

```
Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oActiveDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
Set oSection = CreateObject("Word.Section")
Set oSections = CreateObject("Word.Sections")
Set oTable = CreateObject("Word.Table")
Set oTables = CreateObject("Word.Tables")
```

This approach works for oWordApp and oActiveDoc objects.
It fails at oSection and beyond.

When I'm able to trap an error, it's a 429 error.

Any ideas?  (By the way, there more Word objects needed, just not shown for brevity.  Also, I need to extend this approach to Visio objects used within Excel VBA once I figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `CreateObject` for the *Application*. Once you've created an instance of Word, then use `oWordApp` to create new documents, manipulate tables and sections, and so on.

```
Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oActiveDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add()
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks.  I got this t work (generally).  I found that within called routines I needed to declare my objects "as Objects": "code"

Comment: Hit the timeout on comments. @BigBen Thanks.  I got this to work (generally).  I found that within called routines I needed to declare references "as Objects": i.e. [code] Private Sub Word_Replace_Cover_Graphics(oSection As Object) [code] rather than oActiveDoc.Section.